# How to replace a single quote within a string with a escaped single quote in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm working in R an have a string 
`s = "beta'COP"` and want to convert it into `s2 = "beta\'COP"`.
I tried `gsub("\'", "\\'", s)` but it did not work

I will appreciate any suggestions

Comment: `"beta'COP"` = `"beta\'COP"`. You just need `s2 <- gsub("'", "\\'", s, fixed=TRUE)`. The `"\\"` (a string literal with an escaping ``\`` and a ``\`` char) is a single ``\`` (literal char).

Answer (score 0):

We need

```
s2 <- sub("'", "\\\\'", s)
cat(s2)
#beta\'COP

nchar("\\")
#[1] 1
```

---

It is possible that the OP wanted a double quote

```
sub("'", '"', s)
#[1] "beta\"COP"
```

Comment: no it does not work, it produces "beta\\'COP" but I need "beta\'COP"

Comment: @WasimAftab If you just print with `cat`, it is a single

Comment: s2 <- cat(sub("'", "\\\\'", s)) is NULL; I want it to be in a variable

Comment: nchar - Count The Number Of Characters (Or Bytes Or Width). How is it relevant?